# android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize is not working properly on MobiWire

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to test my app on Mobiwire MobiPrint with Android version 4.2.2

I put this statement in the Activity tag in the manifest file to resize the screen when the soft keyboard is visible

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible|stateAlwaysHidden"
```

this is my XML file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.egpay.merchant.activities.LoginActivity">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/egpay_logo" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/id_wrapper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/EditTextHint">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_id"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_user"
                    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                    android:hint="@string/merchantCode"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                    tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/password_wrapper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/EditTextHint">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_password"
                    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                    tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chk_save_password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:checked="false"
                android:gravity="left|center"
                android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                android:text="@string/savePassword"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="10">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_forget"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/forgetPassword"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_colorful_btn_main"
                    android:text="@string/login"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Link to Login Screen -->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_update"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Update Now" />
        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here's screenshot of the result:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

as you can see when the keyboard is visible the screen resize itself but the keyboard still covering some parts.

what can I do to solve this issue???

note that I tested the app on another device running Android version 5.1.1 and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try like this

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

instead of

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible|stateAlwaysHidden"
```

Comment: is there any other suggestion?